# camel-dropbox - Handle whitespace in dynamic remotePath

Tags: apache-camel

I've a problem with a quite simple use case.

1. search for files in dropbox folder
2. Choose files to load
3. load files from dropbox

This is how I tried it:

```
from("timer:start?period=60m")
  //Load list of files
  .to("dropbox://search?accessToken={{accessToken}}&clientIdentifier={{clientIdentifier}}&remotePath={{remotePath}}")
  //Create list of files to load
  .bean(FileHandlerBean.class, "prepareOperations")
  .split(simple("${body}"))
    //Load file from dropbox
    .recipientList(simple("dropbox://get?accessToken={{accessToken}}&clientIdentifier={{clientIdentifier}}&remotePath=${body.dropBoxFilePath}"))
  [...]
```

Normally this should work, but when the remotePath contains a filename with whitespaces like *2015-05-16 18.43.56.jpg* the *DropboxConfigurationValidator* throws an Exception.

I tried to use the URLEncoder:

```
URLEncoder.encode(dbxEntry.path, "UTF-8")
```

But this doesn't help. 
I debug the component and can see, when the DropBoxComponent get the parameters the "+" was translated back to a whitespace.

Any ideas how I can handle this?

Using the Camel Version 2.17.1

Comment: Thanks you created a JIRA and provided a PR with a fix - that is how its done: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10334

Answer (score 0):

There will be a bugfix for this problem in one of the next camel releases.
Here is the Link for the Jira Ticket: [[CAMEL-10334]](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10334)

Then it's possible to use whitespaces in the remotePath attribute.